# `pointer-events: none;` does not work for iframe in Edge

Tags: html, css, iframe, microsoft-edge

I'm applying `pointer-events: none;` on `iframe`, it works fine in all major browsers except for the Edge (tested with Edge 16).
In Edge, I still can click anything inside the iframe. I've also tried to apply the styling to iframe's parent `div`, but nothing works.
Note: I can't apply it inside of the iframe

```
<div style="pointer-events: none;">
  <iframe>...</iframe>
</div>

<iframe style="pointer-events: none;">...</iframe>
```

Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe content?

Comment: @Alessio no, I don't

Comment: You can try positioning absolute the iframe and give it a negative z-index

Comment: @Alessio it already has fixed position plus negative z-index won't help here

Comment: Ok, try posting full code on a codepen or fiddle, that would things easier to solve!

Comment: @Alessio here is the page I'm doing testing on, hope this works
http://pensive-hypatia-1344fe.bitballoon.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160516/discussion-between-alessio-and-dmitriy-kozyatinskiy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a farther investigation, it seems that this is a bug in Edge v16 (Edge/16.16299), everything works fine in Edge v15 and below.
So, be careful: in Edge v16, `pointer-events: none;` does not affect the iframes in any way, even if you applied it to the parent container.

UPD: I had submitted the bug report to the Edge development team, they have fixed it in April release or so
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14961910/

Answer (score 2):

True, that CSS property it's kind of buggy. Try to add inside app.css the property:

```
.upgrade-banner .row .col.upgrade {
    ...
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to all the clickable items inside your iframe.

Testing this from browserstack (Edge 16) works fine:

[image: Pointer Events on "upgrade" button]

Comment: As I said, I don't have an access to the iframe content

Comment: Ok, so what about adding a pseudoelement which is transparent with a higher z-index?